# Get infos and status from RICOH printer web interface using Playwright and Python

Tags: python, playwright-python

I need get some informations from a printer, how to get this values?
I try...

```
def run(playwright: Playwright) -> None:
ping_status = ping_check(IMP)
if ping_status:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto(F"http://{IMP}{URL}")
    # Extrair o contador
    page.frame_locator("frame[name=\"work\"]").get_by_role("link", name="Status/Informações").click()
    page.frame_locator("frame[name=\"work\"]").get_by_role("link", name="Contador").click()
    table = page.frame_locator("frame[name=\"work\"]").locator("table")
    for row, row_index in zip(table.locator("tr").all(), range(0, 1)):
        for cell, cell_index in zip(row.locator("td").all(), range(0, 4)):
            print(f"Row {row_index}, Cell {cell_index} - Value: '{cell.inner_text()}'")
    # /html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[4]
    #page.frame_locator("frame[name=\"work\"]").get_by_role("link", name="Verificar detalhes").click()

    # ---------------------
    context.close()
    browser.close()
```

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
run(playwright)

[image]

Comment: Please share the actual site and a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen, this URL is from a printer in my job. I tried get total of printed pages, using playwright codegen command.